# Editable UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

how to make `UITableview` editable, I am using `EDITActionsForRowAtIndexPath` delegate for editing cell
My code :

```
let infoAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Destructive, title: "More", handler: { (action , indexPath) -> Void in
            let MoreInfo = UIAlertController(title: "More", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

            MoreInfo.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Flag This conversation", style: .Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                print("flaged")
                self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
                self.tableView.editing = true
            })))


            MoreInfo.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
            print("Cancel")
            self.presentViewController(MoreInfo, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use uialert, try this snippet:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let deleteClosure = { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        println("Delete button pressed")
    }

    let moreClosure = { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        println("More button pressed")
    }

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: deleteClosure)
    let moreAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "More", handler: moreClosure)

    return [deleteAction, moreAction]
}
```

this should show 2 buttons: one red with delete text and one gray with more text; you can customize as you prefer :)

source: http://pablin.org/2014/09/25/uitableviewrowaction-introduction/

Comment: i want to show actionSheet when click on more button 
and in this action Sheet have button
when click this button i want to make this table is editable 
can you help Me ??